# public List<List<string>> MyValue - not generating on client from RIA service - need guidance

Tags: silverlight, ria

I have an object in Ria service that is being generated on the client without a problem.  The only problem is that this property is not being included in the client code and therefore missing it's values.

```
public List<List<string>> MyValue
```

Everything else is fine.  I assume the problem is because it's a List within a List as regular List

I am confused as to what will generate on the client and what won't with RIA services.  Where can I find some guidance about this?

Anyone have any tips on how to solve this because I need these values returned back to the client?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to generate the proxy property on the client by creating my own class called MyStrings which has a single property of type `List<string>.`

Then, in the Tests class i change the object type from `List<List<string>>` to `List<MyStrings>.`

I am not sure why one serializes and one doesn't, but this is a dirty work around I will use for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that a `List<List<string>>` will definitely serialize and deserialize just fine using WCF/RIA. That leads me to believe that perhaps the problem is in your contracts. How are you setting up the service and client proxy?

For example, is `MyValue` a property on an object that you're sending to or receiving from the server? If so, is there a `DataContract` attribute on the class on both the client and server? Is there a `DataMember` attribute on the property of both classes?

Comment: In the DomainService the return type is List<TestSet>, and MyValue is a property of TestSet.  These get generated in a RIA project on the client automatically.

Comment: There is no DataContract attribute, but not sure why it's necessary if all other properties are serializing fine on the same object.

Comment: I assume MyValue is also defined as `List<List<string>>` on the server, yes? It's not *supposed* to be necessary as of .NET 4 to be explicit with DataContract attributes (unless you want to hide data), but I've found WCF can occasionally hiccup if it's trying to serialize a non-DataContract object. I have found it a best practice to always explicitly add DataContract and DataMember attributes.

Comment: MyValue is List<TestSet>, yes you are correct.  I applied the attributes explicitly and still no luck.  It looks like it just doesn't want to serialize and geenrate the proxy code on the client for this property :( ..

Comment: Wait a moment. Is `MyValue` `List<List<string>>` or is it `List<TestSet>`? Because those are two entirely different things, and if they're not exactly the same on both sides, you're not going to be able to deserialize at either end.

Comment: Ooops.  I apologize, I made a mistake in my last comment.  It is defined List<List<string>>.

Comment: Ooops.  I apologize, I made a mistake in my last comment.  It is defined List<List<string>>.  

The client gets generated automatically into a generated file (.g.cs file) that I have no control over.  So, it's not generating this property at all to include it on the client proxy object, but it's generating all the other ones fine.  Not sure why it's picky about List<List<string>> - the serialization is dead simple in my mind....

Comment: Check my answer.  I found a hacked workaround.  Unfortunately, I can find little in terms of guidance from MS around .this